# Using * vs Element Tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm writing a script to scrape some data off the web.

I've copied the XPaths for a few of the same elements on different pages directly from the browser, which produces `//*[@id="priceblock_dealprice"]`.

However, they're all `span` elements. I don't know enough about how XPath works under the hood, but I'm assuming `//span[@id="priceblock_dealprice"]` would obviously be quicker since it only has to check the `span` elements? Is this true?

Is there any benefit to using `*` over, say, `span` in this specific context?

Comment: Why are you using XPath for something that has an ID? Use `By.id()` instead. Either way, you might save a few ms... nothing significant. More likely logic in your script is what is slowing things down. The only way to know is to do some profiling of your code to see where time is spent. Then you can address what is slow and how to fix it.

Comment: @JeffC Why not use XPath? What is the benefit of using `By.ID()` over XPath? It's not that my code is slow, i'm just wondering whether there is any benefit to selecting the `span` element explicitly, since all of the elements are `span` elements, instead of using the wildcard selector as the browser suggests

Comment: `By.id()` is faster, better supported in all browsers, and more clearly indicates what you are doing.

Comment: @JeffC i dont see how its indicates the purpose any more clearly than other methods, but the other reasons are legit

Comment: `By.id()` can only mean one thing... by id. When you use an XPath like `//*[@id="priceblock_dealprice"]` it's by id also... just going through the XPath engine but you have to read it more carefully to see what attributes, tags, etc. are being searched. With `By.id()` the intent is clearer, faster.

Comment: @JeffC to each their own i guess. i dont really notice a different. of course you may have to pay extra attention in some contexts

Comment: @JeffC is there any `By.ID` equivalent to this: `By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]')`?

Comment: No equivalent for `By.id()` but you can use a CSS selector instead and it will probably be twice as fast... `div[id*='100_dealView']`

Comment: @JeffC why is `find_element_by_xpath` so relatively slow?? i'm assuming the `*` in `div[id*='100_dealView_']` means that the `id` contains `100_dealView_`?

Comment: @JeffC sooo `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id*='100_dealView_']')`?? and that would be faster than `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]')`??

Comment: Selenium calls into the CSS selector or XPath engine of the browser to find elements on the page. The CSS selector engine is highly optimized because CSS is what is used to style pages and it needs to be lightning fast. XPath, not so much. Some work has been done in recent years to make XPath faster but it's not as fast as CSS selectors (and probably never will be).

Comment: Yes, `id*=` means id contains. See [this reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not likely to see a huge performance difference by changing `*` to `span`.

The bigger performance impact would be eliminating, or at least constraining, the descendant axis `//`.

With a descendant axis that starts at the root node, you are forcing the XPath engine to walk over the entire node tree and inspect each and every element, which can be expensive with large documents.

If you were to provide any clues about the structure, the engine can avoid a lot of unnecessary work, and should perform better.

For instance:

```
/html/body/section[2]/div//*[@id="priceblock_dealprice"]
```

Besides performance, the other considerations are maintenance and flexibility.

You might get better performance with a more specific XPath, but then changes to the page structure and element names might result in things not matching anymore. You will need to decide what is more important.

Comment: great tip for speeding up the efficiency!! didn't think of that. i actually have been using and likely overusing the `//` axis which is probably why my scripts become so slow after a while.

Comment: Have you tested the performance difference? My guess is that it's negligible... on the order of under 50ms. In UI automation, you won't even see that difference once you hit the second page in a scenario. If you really want to go fast, stop using XPath when you don't need to. CSS selectors are significantly faster... at least twice as fast for an equivalent locator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its better to use 'span' instead of *, but as it is having an ID, so instead of XPath, its better to use By.ID. 
ID will be somewhat fast compared to Xpath.

Comment: why is `By.ID` faster than using XPaths? Is `By.XPATH` also faster than `find_element_by_xpath`??

Comment: @Anthony the `@id` is unique within the document. Functions to lookup by the id value are likely backed by a Map or similar construct that allows for fast and efficient lookups by that key. XPath also has the `id()` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-id

Comment: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/selenium-locators The most efficient way and preferred way to locate an element on a web page is By ID. ID will be the unique on web page which can be easily identified.

Comment: @MadsHansen ok, but the question remains: what is the difference between using XPath to search for an element with a particular ID versus using By to search for an element with a particular ID? That web page is written in broken English and doesn't really demonstrate why using one method to search for an ID is quicker than another method used to search for an ID?

Comment: @MadsHansen so i can't do this: `items = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "100_dealView_")]'))) item.find_element(By.ID, 'dealImage').get_attribute('href')`? how would you rewrite that piece of code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What can't you do? Maybe post this as a separate question, with example HTML and a description of what you are attempting to achieve would be easiest.